# Thread scoped variable counter

Tags: jmeter, performancecounter

Looking to create a jMeter script with thread-local counter. I have a pool of 50000 (1 to 50000) keys and would like to spread them evenly over the number of threads in a threadGroup.  Seems like I could do a simple calculation up front and create a min and max variable (ie: if I had 100 threads and my ${__threadNum} was 2 ... I would be looking at a __counter range of 501 to 1000.  Is there a way to do that calc up front and then just run an efficient thread-scoped variable or function to loop thru the keys within the range for that thread (obviously next run could be 50 threads or 200).  Thanks,